# React Native Reanimated 2 (Animate SVG based on route changed)

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a react functional component `Svg` being used as an icon for the Bottom-TabBar. On route change the current `state.index` is compared to the route `index`. The result which essentially is a boolean state `isFocused` is passed to the Svg.

I am trying to animate the Svg based on this state and can not get the simple operation completed using reanimated. I am most certain that the value of fill is not being updated in `useAnimatedProps` hook but I lack the experience of having deep knowledge with reanimated. Any help will be greatly appreciated

```js
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedProps,
  useSharedValue,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Svg, { Circle, Path } from 'react-native-svg';

const AnimatedSvg = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Svg);

export default ({ isFocused }) => {
  const fill = useSharedValue({ fill: 'transparent' });
  const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
    isFocused
      ? (fill.value = { fill: 'red' })
      : (fill.value = { fill: 'transparent' });

    return fill.value;
  });
  return (
    <AnimatedSvg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={24}
      height={24}
      animatedProps={animatedProps}
      stroke={'white'}
      strokeWidth={2}
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeLinejoin="round"
      className="feather feather-search">
      <Circle cx={11} cy={11} r={8} />
      <Path d="m21 21-4.35-4.35" />
    </AnimatedSvg>
  );
};
```

Comment: Raphael: Thank you for your input. Makes total sense! Accepting your answer,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more common approach would be to use a "progress-variable" as the shared value.

```js
const fillProgress = useSharedValue(isFocused? 1 : 0);
```

You would the use this progress-variable to generate the animatedProps. Please note the use of `interpolateColor` to get the actual interpolated color.

```js
const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
    const fillValue = interpolateColor(fillProgress.value, [0, 1], ["transparent", "red"]);  
    return {
        fill: fillValue
    }
});
```

You have to return an object with the properties you would want to animate. If you wanted to animate fill and opacity for example, you would return `{fill: "", opacity: -1}` with the appropriate values instead of `""` and `-1`. Lastly you have to make the actual element you want to animate Animated. In this case, you want to animate the `Circle`, not the `Svg` so that has to be an Animated object.

```js
const AnimatedCircle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);
```

You can then detect being focused using `useEffect` and animate accordingly.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fillProgress.value = withTiming(isFocused? 1 : 0);
}, [isFocused]);
```

Remember to set the initial value for the `fillProgress` just like you do in the `withTiming` function.

To summarize, you have to animate the element, that uses the animated properties and you *should* use progress-variables as mentioned above.

Here is the full modified code (tested on Android):

```js
import Animated, {
    useAnimatedProps,
    useSharedValue,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Svg, { Circle, Path } from 'react-native-svg';

const AnimatedCircle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);

export default function Icon ({ isFocused }) {
    const fillProgress = useSharedValue(isFocused? 1 : 0);
    const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
        const fillValue = interpolateColor(fillProgress.value, [0, 1], ["transparent", "red"]);  
        return {
            fill: fillValue
        }
    });


    useEffect(() => {
        fillProgress.value = withTiming(isFocused? 1 : 0);
    }, [isFocused]);

    return (
      <Svg
        width={24}
        height={24}
        stroke={'white'}
        strokeWidth={2}
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        className="feather feather-search">
            <AnimatedCircle animatedProps={animatedProps} cx={11} cy={11} r={8} />
            <Path d="m21 21-4.35-4.35" />
      </Svg>
    );
};
```